# Why is only 64kB of data being saved in my MySQL data column?

Tags: php, mysql, text, blob

I am trying to insert a very long text string into a MySQL Blob column, but MySQL is only saving 64kB of the data. The string is 75360 characters long. I am connecting with PHP's `mysql_connect()`.

Any ideas?

Does it make a difference if it's Blob or Text. I originally had it as a Text but changed it with no affect.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because that's the [maximum size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) of a BLOB column.  You need to use MEDIUMBLOB/LONGBLOB or MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT.

Answer (score 6):

A `BLOB` type in MySQL can store up to 65,534 bytes, if you try to store more than this much data MySQL will truncate the data.  `MEDIUMBLOB` can store up to 16,777,213 bytes, and `LONGBLOB` can store up to 4,294,967,292 bytes.

If you enable strict SQL mode ([MySQL modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)) you will get an error when you try to store data that doesn't fit in the column type.

Answer (score 2):

You also asked if there is a difference between BLOB and TEXT
BLOBS are for binary data. If you do a LIKE query on a BLOB field it will be case sensitive.

i.e.

```
SELECT 'TEXT' LIKE 'TEXT';
=> 1 for both BLOB and TEXT

SELECT 'TEXT' LIKE 'text';
=> 1 for TEXT
=> 0 for BLOB
```

Answer (score 0):

The blob column is only 64Kb per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/storage-requirements.html)

Try a mediumblob column type instead...

Comment: Curious to why this attracted an anonymous downvote?