# Ajax send input file image using PDO

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo, ajaxform

After many research i just can´t seem to find the problem with my code and i was hopping anyone could help me. My problem is, i can´t seem to `show/GET` the image after inserted:

### My form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="insert.php" method="post" name="changer">
Name <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name"/> </br>
<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
<input value="Submit" name="submitbtn" type="submit">
</form>
```

**My ajax function**

```
$('#form').on('submit',(function(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  url: 'insert.php',
  type: "POST",
  data:  new FormData(this),
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData:false,
  success: function()
  {
    alert ("ok");

  },
  error: function() 
  {
    alert ("error");
  }                  
 });
}));
```

### my insert.php

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=binary", "root", "pass");
if(!$pdo)
{
    die('Erro ao criar a conexão');
    echo "db error!";
}
else
{
   $statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_images (image,name) VALUES (:image,:name)');

   if (isset($_FILES['image'])) 
   { 
      echo "entrou no file";
      // Temporary file name stored on the server
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  
      $name = $_POST['name'];

      // Read the file 
      $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $data = addslashes($data);
      fclose($fp);

      $statement->bindParam(':image', $data);
     $statement->bindParam(':name', $name);

   if($statement->execute())
   {
      echo "update";
   }
   else
   {  
      echo "no update";
   }          
  }
}
?>
```

After this, i went to my `phpadmin` and i can see the name i have written and also: [BLOB - 64 KiB].

### Now, in my show.php file i have:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=binary", "root", "pass");
if(!$pdo)
{
   die('Erro ao criar a conexão');
}
else
{
    $verb = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

    if ($verb == "GET") 
    {
        header('Content-type: image/jpg');

        $statement = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_images");
        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $statement->execute();

        $img = $result['image'];

        echo $img;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You've got a typo in your `show.php` (missing double quote)

Comment: Thanks you for answering. Where? in my ['image'] it should be ["image"] ? thank you again.

Comment: At the declaration of `$pdo`. Here : `"pass);`. I assume this is not in your original code ?

Comment: It´s not, that´s when i was coping the code to show here, but even with that, it´s not working. But what´s missing in my code?

Comment: Any error in console ? PHP log ? ... Why are you saying it does not work ? What is the expecting behaviour, what do you get for now ? Please provide details...

Comment: the console says GET 200 ok, and that´s why i get confused, also if i erase the header in my show.php and then go to my network/preview tab on chrome, i can see an array saying: PNG and the rest is just strange code. I think this is normal, that´s why i have the header image/jpeg. I also tryied changing the heade to image/png and it doesn´t work also.

Comment: The expect behavior is for the show.php echo the image i have inserted.And it only shows a litle image square with nothing on it.

Comment: I provided an answer to this. You got this little image because it is the filename interpreted by the browser as an image. You have to output the actual content of the file.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. You are saving the file content so everything should be fine. I would personnaly chose to save the file in a directory rather than its content in db.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409761/why-is-only-64kb-of-data-being-saved-in-my-mysql-data-column) might be a solution to your problem